# Copy all users' .bash_history in one go

Tags: linux, bash, command-history

Is it possible to use cp to copy every user's .bash_history file into the same folder (with the username appended)?

Or is it at least possible to copy them into a parallel set of folders? I can't seem to figure this out.

I do have root access.

Comment: Just a thought from a sysadmin; what you're suggesting is sort of like a security guard rooting through employees desks and lockers.  Sure, it's company property and if your boss tells you to, that's one thing; but if they're not properly informed that you intend to do so, I'd expect some backlash.  If I found someone did that to me, I'd immediately quit; that's great excuse to move on to a higher paying job.

Comment: I would not quit over it (well, not until I found a better job), but I would start looking around. and I would point them to local law (dutch) which makes that illegal unless it in the 'employee/computer rules'. If it is not in there then you are doing illegal things. (Which means that if your boss orders you to do that you print a copy of the email and keep it in a safe place. Or go to legal and talk with them). --- Now that is from a professional IT'er legal view. If you are at home with a server and a few friends things kind a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr;** 
`for a in /home/* ; do cp $a/.bash_history /tmp/$a.bash_history ; done`

**Longer version:**

for a in pattern loops over all items in a pattern.
The pattern itself is stores in the variable called *a*.

Examples:
 `for a in * ; do echo $a ; done` echo's all filenames.
 `for a in /home/* ; do echo $a ; done` echo's the names of all homedirs in /home.

Instead of *echo* we use the copy command. (cp)

And since we do not want to overwrite all files we either need to change the destination name, or we need to concatenate them all in one file.

.bash_history

To copy we use *cp $a /tmp/$a_file* (all files are now named differently.

To concattenate we can use cat with append to redirection.
`for a in /home/* ; do cat $a/.bash_history >> /tmp/all-users_bash_history ; done`

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you! That got the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Remember this is NOT a totally fool proof way to copy a users' activity.  This is because there are options that the user can easily invoke to not put things in the history file.  So I would not count on this as any sort of auditing mechanism.

Also, as a root user, spying on other users' file unless there are specific and valid reasons for doing so is a little suspect.  Lacks a little integrity here, unless you tell them up front that you are going to do this.

Comment: In this case, the entire class is snooping on the activity of the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something in particular, you can use:

```
grep -e "stuff goes here" /home/*/.bash_history
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31723/can-i-search-bash-history-across-all-users-on-a-server/31731#31731)